# transition-group without wrapping in a span

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to apply a transition to a Vuetify v-data-table so that when I delete a tbody in my table, it fades out instead of just vanishing off the screen.  If I wrap the tbody in a transition-group the tbody fades out as expected.  However, it's wrapped in a span tag which means all of the columns in the tbody get shoved into the first column of my table.

[image]

I know I can specify a different tag other than a span, but they all cause my table layout to break.  How can I apply a fade transition to the tbody and maintain my table layout?

```
  <v-data-table
    ref="dataTable"
    :headers="headers"
    fixed-header
    :height="height"
    :items="invoices"
    item-key="id"
    :search="search"
    class="elevation-1"
    disable-pagination
    :loading="loading"
    loading-text="Loading invoices... please wait..."
    :no-data-text="this.noDataText"
    no-results-text="No invoices found for your search."
    :hide-default-footer="true"
  >
    <template v-slot:headers="props">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th
            v-for="header in props.headers"
            :key="header.text"
            ref="dataTableHdr"
            :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '', header.class === '']"
            @click="changeSort(header.value)"
          >
            <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:body="{ items }">
      <transition-group tag="boo" name="invoice">
        <tbody v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id" @click="items.splice(index,1)">
          <tr>
            <td
              :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
              valign="top"
              class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
            >{{ item.vendorCode }}</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.vendorName }}</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
            <td>CONTENT</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </transition-group>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
```

---

**Revised Code:**

```
<template v-slot:body="{ items }">
  <tbody v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
    <transition-group tag="tbody" name="invoice">
      <tr key="row1">
        <td
          :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
          valign="top"
          class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
        >{{ item.vendorCode }}</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>
          <v-btn @click="reject(items, index)" class="mx-2" v-blur fab small>
            <v-icon color="red">mdi-cancel</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr key="row2">
        <td>{{ item.vendorName }}</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
        <td>CONTENT</td>
      </tr>
    </transition-group>
  </tbody>
</template>

<style>
.invoice-leave-active tr,
.invoice-leave-active tr:hover {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
.invoice-enter-active,
.invoice-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.invoice-enter, .invoice-leave-to /* .invoice-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

---

Here is my final, super complex template, using v-if with changing the item.id to null.

```
<template v-slot:body="{ items }">
  <transition-group tag="tbody" name="invoice" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <tr
      key="row1"
      v-if="item.id"
      :class="[item.duplicate ? 'duplicateItemRow' : '', {'success': item.id===selectedId}]"
    >
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
      >{{ item.vendorCode }}</td>
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
      >{{ item.vendorName }}</td>
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium nowrap"
      >{{ item.poNumber }}</td>
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
      >
        <v-tooltip bottom>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <a
              :href="`/rvimain.pgm?rqstyp=senchcall1&isys=a&i7=INV&i4=${item.invoiceNumber}&i6=${item.poNumber}`"
              class="pa-0 ma-0"
              v-on="on"
              target="_blank"
            >{{ item.invoiceNumber }}</a>
          </template>
          <span>Click to view invoice</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </td>
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 pr-6 text-right font-weight-medium"
      >{{ item.invoiceDate | moment("M/D/YYYY") }}</td>
      <td :class="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : ''"></td>
      <td
        valign="top"
        :class="['pt-3', 'font-weight-medium', 'nowrap', item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : '']"
      >
        <div v-if="item.duplicate">{{ item.duplicate }}</div>
        <div
          v-if="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount"
        >${{ item.poAmount | currency }} PURCHASE ORDER DOES NOT MATCH INVOICE</div>
      </td>
      <td :class="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : ''"></td>
      <td :class="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : ''"></td>
      <td :class="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : ''"></td>
      <td :class="item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : ''">
        <CommentsDialog
          v-if="item.invoiceSections[0].comments"
          :itemId="item.invoiceSections[0].id"
          :comments="item.invoiceSections[0].comments"
        />
      </td>
      <td
        valign="top"
        :class="['pt-3', 'text-right', 'font-weight-medium', 'nowrap', item.invoiceAmount !== item.poAmount ? 'amountMismatchItemRow' : '']"
      >{{ item.invoiceAmount | currency }}</td>
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-center"
      >
        <div v-if="item.approvalDate && !item.rejectedDate">
          <v-icon color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>
        </div>
        <div
          v-if="!item.duplicate && !item.approvalDate && !item.rejectedDate && item.invoiceAmount === item.poAmount"
          class="mb-4"
        >
          <v-tooltip bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-btn @click="approveInvoice(item)" v-on="on" v-blur class="mx-2" fab small>
                <v-icon color="green">mdi-check</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </template>
            <span>Approve invoice</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </div>
        <RejectButton
          v-if="!item.approvalDate && !item.rejectedDate"
          :invoice="item"
          @removeInvoice="removeInvoice"
        />
        <div v-if="!item.approvalDate && item.rejectedDate">
          <v-icon color="red" class="mb-4">mdi-cancel</v-icon>
          <div>
            Rejected
            <br />
            {{item.rejectedDate | moment("M/D/YYYY")}}
            <br />
            {{ item.rejectedBy }}
            <br />
            <RejectReasonDialog
              v-if="item.rejectedReason"
              :itemId="item.id"
              :reason="item.rejectedReason"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <!-- SECTIONS -->
    <template v-for="(section, index) in item.invoiceSections">
      <tr
        v-if="item.id && section.length > 0 && section.sectionDescription != ''"
        :class="item.duplicate ? 'duplicateItemRow' : 'darkTableRow'"
        :key="`${item.id}.${index}`"
      >
        <td class="text-left" colspan="2">{{ section.sectionDescription }}</td>
        <td class="text-left" colspan="3">{{ section.repairReason }}</td>
        <td class="text-right nowrap">{{ section.sectionTotal | currency }}</td>
        <td>
          <CommentsDialog
            v-if="section.comments"
            :itemId="section.id"
            :comments="section.comments"
          />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!-- ITEMS -->
      <tr
        :class="[item.duplicate ? 'duplicateItemRow' : '', item.qtyRequested != item.qtyReceived ? 'qtyMismatchItemRow' : '' ]"
        v-show="item.id"
        v-for="(item, index) in section.invoiceItems"
        :key="`${item.id}.${item.id}.${index}`"
      >
        <td class="text-left">{{ item.partNumber }}</td>
        <td class="text-left">{{ item.partDescription }}</td>
        <td class="text-right">
          <v-tooltip v-if="item.qtyRequested != item.qtyReceived" bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <span v-on="on" class="help">{{ item.qtyReceived }}</span>
            </template>
            <span>Requested {{ item.qtyRequested }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <span v-else>{{ item.qtyReceived }}</span>
        </td>
        <td
          :class="['text-right nowrap nopaddingRight', item.each > item.avgChargeAmount && item.avgChargeAmount != 0 ? 'over help' : '', 
        item.each < item.avgChargeAmount && item.avgChargeAmount != 0 ? 'under help' : '']"
        >
          <v-tooltip
            v-if="item.each != item.avgChargeAmount && item.avgChargeAmount != 0"
            bottom
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <span v-on="on">{{ item.each | currency }}</span>
            </template>
            <span>Avg price: ${{ item.avgChargeAmount | currency }}</span>
          </v-tooltip>
          <span v-else>{{ item.each | currency }}</span>
        </td>
        <td
          :class="['text-left nowrap lowpaddingLeft', item.each > item.avgChargeAmount && item.avgChargeAmount != 0 ? 'over' : '', 
        item.each < item.avgChargeAmount && item.avgChargeAmount != 0 ? 'under' : '']"
        >
          <v-tooltip v-if="item.nationalAccount" bottom>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <span v-on="on" class="help">N</span>
            </template>
            <span>
              National
              <br />Account
            </span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right nowrap">{{ item.lineTotal | currency }}</td>
        <td class="text-left">
          <v-btn
            outlined
            small
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-if="item.comments"
            @click.stop="$set(dialogComments, item.id, true)"
          >Comments</v-btn>
          <CommentsDialog v-if="item.comments" :itemId="item.id" :comments="item.comments" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
    <tr key="row3" v-if="item.id">
      <td colspan="13" class="divider">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </transition-group>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transition group **as** your tbody, with the tag attribute like `tag="tbody"`. So the transition group will display as a tbody instead of a span. The immediate children of the transition group also need unique keys and a v-if or v-show condition. The if or show condition also has to be triggered after whatever content you're looping through is ready, in order to se the transition. The click function will work inside of your table, but not on the tbody.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

```
<transition-group tag="tbody" name="invoice" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    <tr key="row1" v-if="showRow">
        // Your columns
    </tr>
    <tr key="row2" v-if="showRow">
        // Your columns
    </tr>
</transition-group>
```

You can also use a tbody with the `is` attribute: is="transition-group", but I prefer the above option because the required `name` attribute of transition-group is not an allowed attribute of tbody. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is

```
<tbody is="transition-group" name="invoice">
    ...
</tbody>
```

Comment: Tried that, several times.  I get an error "<transition-group> children must be keyed".

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko Ah correct, the immediate children of the transition group need unique keys. I updated the answer. :)

Comment: I posted the latest version of my code. While it creates valid HTML and everything is in the right place, the transitions do no occur.

Comment: Updated with another possible solution using the "is" attribute. :)

Comment: Sorry to be such a pain. Columns line up again, but there is no transition and clicking on the row does nothing. The click only works if I move it to the row.

Comment: No worries. I adjusted my answer again and tested to make sure it works. The main difference is that the click doesn't work on tbody, I believe that's just an HTML thing, and you do need some sort of conditional v-if on any element directly inside of the transition, that has to be triggered after the other content you're looping through has been loaded, which may require a setTimeout unless it's triggered by a click.

Comment: Still cannot get the transition to work.  The click on tbody was just for testing. I modified above. I have a button that will do the splice. I have been working on this for nearly a week, so far nothing works. And it should be simple and baked into Vue.

Comment: What are you triggering the transition with? I don't see the v-if or v-show on your rows. If you want to have the rows fade out when you delete them, then you should have some sort of variable in your row v-if that on "delete" would return false, and trigger the transition. That has to be on the immediate children of the transition group.