# Vue transition-group for table with multiple rows in tbody

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using the following code, I am able to get valid HTML, a table with multiple tbody tags each with two rows.

```
<template v-slot:body="{ items }">
  <tbody is="transition-group" name="invoice" v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
    <tr key="row1">
      <td
        :rowspan="updateRowCount(item.invoiceSections)"
        valign="top"
        class="pt-3 text-left font-weight-medium"
      >{{ item.vendorCode }}</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>
        <v-btn @click="items.splice(index,1)" class="mx-2" v-blur fab small>
          <v-icon color="red">mdi-cancel</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr key="row2">
      <td>{{ item.vendorName }}</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
      <td>CONTENT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

All looks formatted as expected.  Problem is the transition never runs.  The tbody should highlight in yellow and then fade out when click my delete button.

```
<style scoped>
.invoice-leave-active,
.invoice-leave-active tr:hover {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
.invoice-enter-active,
.invoice-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.invoice-enter,
.invoice-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

I've looked at hundreds of posts and nearly all deal with just a single table row inside the tbody. Is there a way to treat two rows as a single object as far as transitions are concerned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [transition-group without wrapping in a span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669544/transition-group-without-wrapping-in-a-span)

Comment: I kinda gave up, ended up using what feels dirty but works. I change the item.id to null. With a v-if on the tr the item fades out and drops out of the DOM. The result is the item no longer shows on the screen.  Just kinda klunky and not as smooth of a transition as I would like. If I was showing a single tr this would be less of a problem. My multiple tr for each item makes it more tricky.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I think that solution is the only way to do what you're trying to do with a table. Tables have their limitations. If my answer on your original question has the solution, it would be good to mark it as the accepted answer so others can see it's a working solution. If not, let me know the issues and I'll fix it. :)